# Pinch Gesture with image sequence iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uipinchgesturerecognizer

Is there a way to play through a sequence of images using the Pinch Gesture tool in XCode? If so, how?

Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Dave.

Answer (score 0):

this is the common solution , by adding pinchGesture in every imageView and this calls the callback delegate , when ever the gesture event starts.

```
 for (int i = 0;i<=8;i++){
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init]
 imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] 
     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
 pinch.delegate = self;
 pinch.tag = self;
 [imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
 }

- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer
  {
    //handle pinch...
  }
```